# Is there something that can expand to 12 times it's size on the x & y axis (not concerned about the z), and can still return to it's original shape?

Tags: design, mechanical

I posted this over on physics, they suggested I cross-post it here.

I've been looking for a solid square (non-pourus) that can expand to 12x it's size and back again. This needs to grow and shrink on only the x and y axis, I prefer for the z to stay flat on one/both sides but it really doesn't matter whether it changes or not. The expansion and retraction needs to be done smoothly or in small increments and equally (not x first then y or vice versa). This process needs to be done more than once. I was thinking an elastic material but some materials stay permanently stretched once crossing a certain point, staying too long, or show marks of stretching when restored (like a balloon after someone pulls it). Most of the heat-based ideas I've found either don't change to the size requirements or are one-time solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of synthetic materials like lycra or rubber have even better expansion capabilities. Stretch a lycra sleeve over a pantograph/scissor mechanism frame including diagonal supports that prevent buckling/distortion.

Comment: Thank you very much. My big concern is that some materials show signs of stretching after staying for some time and returning. Does Lyrca have that problem?

Comment: @Questioning: that largely depends on the time it remains stretched. All materials will suffer wear sooner or later, in all applications; it's a futile endeavor seeking one that won't suffer it at all, instead you find one that will outlast the planned lifetime of the product.